# Chosen-Ciphertext Attack on Rabin: Factorize n

Tags: rabin-cryptosystem

At the end of this [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_cryptosystem#Decryption) section, you can see that $$\gcd(|r-s|,n)=q$$ or $$\gcd(|r-s|,n)=p$$ holds. I don't understand why.

Comment: Take the equations for $r$ and $s$ given above the part you reference and write out $r-s$.

Answer (score 2):

By following the above advice (taking the equations for r and s given in the article and writing r-s) you will notice that q is  a divisor, therefore GCD(|r-s|,n) cannot be 1. There are only two options left since n is only divisible by q and p.